# Logging data from High Precision AD/DA board using Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: raspbian, python, analog-to-digital, hat, real-time

I have a High Precision AD/DA board from waveshare with Raspberry Pi 3B (running on Raspbian). With this setup, I get a sampling rate of above 20KPS at my terminal display.

However, I can write only 27 samples in 1s in my CSV file. I am using this Python code for writing to a CSV file. It seems my code is not optimized for writing at a higher sampling rate.

Could you let me know how can I write the data to my CSV file above 10 KPS sampling rate?

Note: I use following statment for writing to a CSV file :

```
data=str(a[0])+','+str(a[1])+','+str(a[2])+','+str(a[3])+','+str(a[4])+','+str(a[5])+','+str(a[6])+','+str(a[7])+','+str(time.time())
```

Thanks

Comment: that statement does not write to a file

Comment: Hi, I am just using this data variable to store each row and then further writing the data to the CSV file using standard procedure.